# Maintain the area of a polygon when offsetting one side

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, polygons

I have an irregular polygon with the a specific area (area_red). How can I get the (parallel) offset value (y) of n selected sides in order to maintain the same area (area _red = area_green) when (parallel) offsetting one side by x?

[image]

Comment: One complication is that, if you select edge $e_i$ to expand by $y$, and neither edge $e_{i-1}$ nor $e_{i+1}$ expands, then $e_i$ might shrink to zero length before enough area is gained to compensate for the movement of $x$.

Comment: ...Okay, I guess I will simply loop trough the offsets constanstly and check each time if the area is the same. lol.